# Grouping and stacking data

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

A sample of my data is :

```r
dat <- read.table(text = " ID   BC1 DC1 DE1 MN2 DC2 PO2 SA3 BC3 KL3 AA4 AP4 BC4 PO4
        1   2   1   2   3   1   3   1   1   3   2   2   2   2
        2   3   1   1   2   3   1   1   2   3   1   1   3   2
        3   2   3   2   3   2   3   2   1   1   3   1   1   1
        4   3   3   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   2   1   2", header = TRUE)
```

I want to get the following table and missing data are blank

```
ID Group1  Group2  Group3  Group4
 1      2       1       2      
 2      3       1       1      
 3      2       3       2      
 4      3       3       1      
 1      3       1       3      
 2      2       3       1      
 3      3       2       3      
 4      1       1       1      
 1      1       1       3      
 2      1       2       3      
 3      2       1       1      
 4      1       2       2      
 1      2       2       2      2
 2      1       1       3      2
 3      3       1       1      1
 4      1       2       1      2
```

The number in front of each column is where the columns are separated from each other. For example BC1, DC1 and DE1. They form the first four rows with their Ids and MN2, DC2 and PO2 form the second rows with their IDs and so on.

Comment: I do not understand the logic of how to transform from `dat` to your output. What happens to `BC`, `DC`, and the other seven groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the row numbers with some pivoting?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat |>
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_sep = "(?=\\d)", names_to = c(NA, "id")) |>
  group_by(ID, id) |>
  mutate(name = row_number()) |>
  pivot_wider(c(ID, id), names_prefix = "Group") |>
  arrange(id) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-id)
```

Or using a map:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

paste(1:4) |> # unique(readr::parse_number(names(dat |> select(-ID))))
  map(\(x) select(dat, ID, ends_with(x)) |> rename_with(\(x) names(x) <- paste0("Group", 1:length(x)), -ID)) |> 
  bind_rows()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 16 × 5
      ID Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4
   <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
 1     1      2      1      2     NA
 2     2      3      1      1     NA
 3     3      2      3      2     NA
 4     4      3      3      1     NA
 5     1      3      1      3     NA
 6     2      2      3      1     NA
 7     3      3      2      3     NA
 8     4      1      1      1     NA
 9     1      1      1      3     NA
10     2      1      2      3     NA
11     3      2      1      1     NA
12     4      1      2      2     NA
13     1      2      2      2      2
14     2      1      1      3      2
15     3      3      1      1      1
16     4      1      2      1      2
```

**Update 13-01:** Now the first solution returns the correct `ID` (not id) + another approach added.

Answer (score 2):

Would be interesting to see if there is an easier approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat |> 
  pivot_longer(-ID) |> 
  mutate(id = str_extract(name, "\\d$")) |> 
  group_by(ID, id) |> 
  mutate(name = paste0("Group", row_number())) |>
  ungroup() |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) |> 
  arrange(id, ID) |> 
  select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 16 × 5
#>       ID Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4
#>    <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#>  1     1      2      1      2     NA
#>  2     2      3      1      1     NA
#>  3     3      2      3      2     NA
#>  4     4      3      3      1     NA
#>  5     1      3      1      3     NA
#>  6     2      2      3      1     NA
#>  7     3      3      2      3     NA
#>  8     4      1      1      1     NA
#>  9     1      1      1      3     NA
#> 10     2      1      2      3     NA
#> 11     3      2      1      1     NA
#> 12     4      1      2      2     NA
#> 13     1      2      2      2      2
#> 14     2      1      1      3      2
#> 15     3      3      1      1      1
#> 16     4      1      2      1      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the data with a specified pattern (`"index1_index2"`), i.e.

```
#   ID 1_1 1_2 1_3 2_1 2_2 2_3 3_1 3_2 3_3 4_1 4_2 4_3 4_4
# 1  1   2   1   2   3   1   3   1   1   3   2   2   2   2
# 2  2   3   1   1   2   3   1   1   2   3   1   1   3   2
# 3  3   2   3   2   3   2   3   2   1   1   3   1   1   1
# 4  4   3   3   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   2   1   2
```

so that you can add the special element `".value"` to `names_to` when using `pivot_longer()` to stack multiple columns that are grouped by that pattern.

###### Code

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  rename_with(~ sub('\\D+', '', .x) %>%
                paste(., ave(., ., FUN = seq), sep = '_'), -ID) %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c("set", ".value"), names_sep = '_') %>%
  arrange(set) %>%
  select(-set)
```

###### Output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 5
      ID   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     2     1     2    NA
 2     2     3     1     1    NA
 3     3     2     3     2    NA
 4     4     3     3     1    NA
 5     1     3     1     3    NA
 6     2     2     3     1    NA
 7     3     3     2     3    NA
 8     4     1     1     1    NA
 9     1     1     1     3    NA
10     2     1     2     3    NA
11     3     2     1     1    NA
12     4     1     2     2    NA
13     1     2     2     2     2
14     2     1     1     3     2
15     3     3     1     1     1
16     4     1     2     1     2
```